# ChildEventListener not populating listview properly

Tags: android, android-listview

I am trying to work with ChildEventListener in Firebase to populate the listView with the "title" field of every child nodes. But it's not working properly. My first activity is **AuthActivity**, which contains googleSignIn Button, by which the user can log in or authenticate. After that, in **MainActivity** a listView supposes to populate with the data using ChildEventListener datasnapshot. But it remains blank.

**The interesting part is**, If I go back to the **AuthActivity** with the back button pressed and again click the login button, it agains taking me to the MainActivity and somehow this time it's shows the listView with the correct data. And after closing the app, the same error happens. ***I am not getting any errors in the Logcat***.

Here is my AuthActivity File

```
    public class AuthActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 100;

    SignInButton signInButton;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_auth);

        signInButton = findViewById(R.id.signInButton);

        signInButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // Choose authentication providers
                List<AuthUI.IdpConfig> providers = Arrays.asList(
                        new AuthUI.IdpConfig.GoogleBuilder().build());

                // Create and launch sign-in intent
                startActivityForResult(
                        AuthUI.getInstance()
                                .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                                .setAvailableProviders(providers)
                                .build(),
                        RC_SIGN_IN);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            IdpResponse response = IdpResponse.fromResultIntent(data);

            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(AuthActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Login Failed! Please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And The MainActivity File

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 100;
    ListView listView;
    ArrayList<String> titlesArray;

    FirebaseDatabase database;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    FirebaseUser user;
    ChildEventListener childEventListener;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);
        titlesArray = new ArrayList();

        //Get the associated login user info
        user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

        //Write a message to the database
        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        databaseReference = database.getReference().child("notes").child(user.getUid());

        //Adding adapter to the list of titles
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, titlesArray);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        childEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                Note notes = dataSnapshot.getValue(Note.class);
                titlesArray.add(notes.getTitle());
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Loading failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        };

        databaseReference.addChildEventListener(childEventListener);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle item selection
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.sign_out_menu:
                AuthUI.getInstance()
                        .signOut(this);
                return true;
            case R.id.add_new:
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is because you are not notifying adapter after getting data from firebase callback.

Just replace your listener like below.

```
childEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        Note notes = dataSnapshot.getValue(Note.class);
        titlesArray.add(notes.getTitle());
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Loading failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks, man! You just saved my bottom! 

N.B. Although, if anyone interested out there, I have to notifyDataSetChanged() instead of notifyItemInserted() for using ListView.